# What are the standard connectors used on 12V hobby batteries?

Tags: pcb, batteries, connector, 12v

I'm looking for a right-angle PCB board mate for the standard 12V hobby battery connectors.

Where can I find these connectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also called the **"(Standard or Large) Tamiya Connector"** in R/C speak ([ref](http://www.batteryspace.com/connectoradaptorstandardmaletamiyaconnectorwith14awgwires5long.aspx)); not sure if other manufacturers make them (guaranteed someone somewhere does), but here are the [Molex](http://www.molex.com/) part numbers (Digi-Key) *for the Wire-to-Wire connectors*:

#### Device Side (usually)

- Plug - 35143-0201 ([WM2308-ND](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=WM2308-ND))
- Socket - 35728-0201 ([WM2311-ND](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=WM2311-ND))

#### Battery Side

- Cap - 35141-0201 ([WM2309-ND](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?lang=en&site=US&WT.z_homepage_link=hp_go_button&KeyWords=WM2309-ND&x=0&y=0))
- Pin - 35727-0201 ([WM2310-ND](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=WM2310-ND))

Molex does not make this style in Wire-to-Board; so any knockoffs of just Molex product probably won't either.

An easy-to-use replacement with both Wire-to-Wire and Wire-to-Board that I've used are the Molex Mini MATE-N-LOK 2 connectors ([like these](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&site=us&keywords=A32471&x=0&y=0)), depending on the current you may need regular MATE-N-LOK.

Comment: Looks like Molex discontinued those parts back in 2011 - DigiKey still has the part number pages but none in stock. See [here](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/PCNs/Molex/10494770_35141,35143_Series_Obs.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

*"The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from."* -- Andrew S. Tanenbaum.

There are a variety of standard [12 VDC power connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector).
Perhaps the most common are:

- Anderson Powerpole (formerly Sermos)
- Deans Ultra
- Gold Bullet Connectors
- Tamiya connectors

Many battery packs have a wire soldered directly to the battery with one of these connectors on the other end of the wire.

There seem to be quite a few people on the internet comparing these connectors.
( [a](http://rc.runryder.com/helicopter/t659659p1/) [b](http://www.radioracecar.com/pitlane/article.aspx?a=4286) [c](http://hobbyunicorn.com.au/categories/Plugs/) [d](http://www.rcuniverse.com/forum/m_3910474/printable.htm) [e](http://www.helifreak.com/archive/index.php/t-21729.html) [f](http://www.tamiyaclub.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php?t2747.html) [g](http://www.helifreak.com/showthread.php?t=56967) )

There are PCB mount connectors that fit PowerPole connectors ([h](http://www.connex-electronics.com/?url=/html/products/anderson/anderson_main_select.html)).
I've also seen PCB-mount high-current spade connectors.

Comment: Your 'h' link issues an alert.  Is that the page you wanted it to point to?  Try opening it in incognito/private mode...

Comment: @KevinVermeer: The connex-electronics link looks OK to me, both incognito mode or normal. It shows high-current PCB mount connectors. What do you see? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I see this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NAJs0.png  I don't know if there's anything you can do about it....

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no standard for 12V hobby battery connectors, so if you are designing a new product or working on your own gear then by all means feel free to pick your own connector type.

If you have any choice at all go with Deans style connectors in stead, the Tamiya connectors are utter shit, they have comparatively high resistance and will get loose and unreliable with a little use.